# Timer updating pictureBox on click error in C#

Tags: c#, forms, timer, picturebox

I have the following code-

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _soundplayer.Play();
        timer1_Tick();

    }


    private void timer1_Tick()
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[imgIndex++];

    }
```

For some reason this brings back the error in the `Form1.Designer.cs` -

```
Error 1 No overload for 'timer1_Tick' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'
```

When button1 is clicked the image in pictureBox1 should change every 2 seconds with the timer tick, however I can't get past this error. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tick event is an event of type EventHandler.  It requires two arguments for the event handler:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[imgIndex++];
}
```

Which requires you to modify the Click event handler like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _soundplayer.Play();
    timer1_Tick(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Using the designer to add event handlers can keep you out of trouble like this.  Select the timer, click the lightning bolt icon in the Properties window and double-click Tick.

Comment: Thats great! It removes the error however the timer is ticking before the button is clicked? So the timer doesn't seem to be controlled by the button but I dont want it to start until the timer is pushed? I will mark as correct.

Comment: Use the button's Click event to set the timer's Enabled property instead.

Comment: Your next question is going to ask how to stop the timer.  Start a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Start timer, when you clicked on a button. And set timer interval to 2000 milliseconds. Timer_tick event will be created automatically every 2 seconds.

```
    private void timer1_Tick()
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[imgIndex++];

    }       
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _soundplayer.Play();
        timer1_Start();
    }
```

Comment: timer1_Tick happens when you click button1, and the properties of the timer are set to being enabled and 2000. This does not resolve the error I stated?